# Mysql ON UPDATE CASCADE - how to properly setup

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to update a value in my parent table but it's updating multiple rows on the child table using ON UPDATE CASCADE.
Here's my schema:

Parent table:

```
Columns: ID, stt_id 
constraint FK_STATUS_ID foreign key (stt_id) references status_d  (stt_id) (status_d is another table that have status types)
```

Child table:

```
Columns: User_id, stt_id
constraint FK_STATUS_ID foreign key (stt_id) references parent_table (stt_id) ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

But when I try to update a row in my parent table, let's say the first row with `stt_id = Inactive`, it's updating all rows on my child table to inactive! This behavior changes depending on which row I update, for instance, updating the last row on parent, it's change the first and last row on child.

Comment: While I am not sure what "updating the last row on parent, it's change the first and last row on child" means, "updating all rows on my child table" is literally what `on update cascade` is supposed to do: it updates the/all values (in stt_id) in the referring table (here: child) when you change the corresponding value (stt_id) in the referenced table (parent). This doesn't seem to be what you intended, but we don't really know what you want instead. It seems odd though that the child table references parent_table, it should probably reference `status_d` too (which might fix your problem).

Comment: thanks for the help @Solarflare , If I reference status_d will fix.  But I want to update the child value when I update the parent value (referenced as FK) 
If I reference the child directly on the status_d I will need to set the status  both on the parent and the child programatically.

Comment: So if I understand correctly, I misuderstand the use of UPDATE CASCADE. So what I'm trying to achieve is: Does mysql have a way to update a non-primary value to all childs from the parent table?

Comment: Can a child ever have another status than its parent?

Comment: @RenanSS I still do not really know what you are trying to do exactly. Can you add some sample data and the expected change when you e.g. update one parent row? Technically, you can use fks on non-primary keys, although the need for it is often a warning signal that you have some flaw in your model (if e.g. parent_table.id is the same as child_table.user_id, you do not need to (or rather: should not) repeat the status in the child table, as you can (or rather: are expected to) simply join; if it's a tree/hierarchy, it's a different situation - but adding some sample data might clear that up).